# Testdriven.NET can't find assembly for project with VS2015 and Xunit

Tags: c#, unit-testing, testdriven.net

I can successfully run Xunit tests in a VS2015 project from the command line with:

```
dnx test
```

but when attempting to use Testdriven.NET from within Visual Studio, it is returning a message *Can't find assembly for project*.  Also the Visual Studio *Test Explorer* doesn't seem to be finding the tests either.

Presumably the tests are constructed correctly if they run from the command line, so I was wondering what else might be missing.

Here is the project.json as requested by Lukasz.

```
{
"version": "1.0.0-*",
"description": "",
"authors": [ "" ],
"tags": [ "" ],
"projectUrl": "",
"licenseUrl": "",
"tooling": {
  "defaultNamespace": "<%= namespace %>"
},
"dependencies": {
    "xunit": "2.1.0",
    "xunit.runner.dnx": "2.1.0-rc1-build204"
},
"commands": {
    "test": "xunit.runner.dnx"
},
"frameworks": {
    "dnx451": { }
}
```

}

Comment: Please show us project.json

Comment: Same issue here. Upvoted.